# I need help with properly initlizing a structure and passing it into a function properly

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, structure

I am writing a simple C++ database, using Visual Studio 2008 express edition, like program to sort and search a text file containing NCAA winners and runner ups by year, this data is to be saved within a structure.  I understand how to do the sorting and searching but i am having trouble with properly initializing the structure and passing it into a function, as when i try to do it how i was shown in class i get several errors that i have been unable to get rid of, any help would be greatly appreciated.

The errors are as follows;

> project5.cpp(145) : error C2676: binary `'['` : `'Data'` does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
>
> project5.cpp(145) : error C2228: left of `'.year'` must have class/struct/union
>
> project5.cpp(146) : error C2676: binary `'['` : `'Data'` does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
>
> project5.cpp(146) : error C2228: left of `'.schoolWin'` must have class/struct/union
>
> project5.cpp(147) : error C2676: binary `'['` : `'Data'` does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
>
> project5.cpp(147) : error C2228: left of `'.scoreWin'` must have class/struct/union
>
> project5.cpp(148) : error C2676: binary `'['` : `'Data'` does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
>
> project5.cpp(148) : error C2228: left of `'.schoolRunnerUp'` must have class/struct/union
>
> project5.cpp(149) : error C2676: binary `'['` : `'Data'` does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
>
> project5.cpp(149) : error C2228: left of `'.scoreRunnerUp'` must have class/struct/union
>
> project5.cpp(191) : error C2664: `'initializeStructure'` : cannot convert parameter 1 from `'Data [100]'` to `'Data &'`

My Structure Declaration:

```
const int Size = 100;           // size of structure
struct Data {                   // Struct definintion to take in stats
    int year;
    string schoolWin;
    int scoreWin;
    string schoolRunnerUp;
    int scoreRunnerUp;
} NCAAStats [Size] ;
void initializeStructure(Data& NCAAStats,  int Size);  // initialization function prototype

//function declaration
void initializeStructure(Data& NCAAStats,  int Size) {
    int Idx;
    for (Idx = 0; Idx < Size; Idx++) {
        NCAAStats[Idx].year = 0000;//line145
        NCAAStats[Idx].schoolWin = "winning school";//line146
        NCAAStats[Idx].scoreWin = 000;//line147
        NCAAStats[Idx].schoolRunnerUp = "losing school";//line148
        NCAAStats[Idx].scoreRunnerUp = 000;//line149
    }
}
//initalize the array of structures
initializeStructure(NCAAStats, Size);//line 191 function call from within main
```

Based off the last error i was thinking that it is possible that for some reason visual studio thinks my structure is named Data with a size of 100 when, it is NCAAStats of size 100, but i am not sure what i did wrong that is causing this, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared an array `NCAAStats[Size]` at the global scope.  However, your functions have arguments called `NCAAStats`; these *hide* the global definition.   Therefore, stuff like `NCAAStats[Idx]` is invalid, because that `NCAAStats` is a `Data &`, not a `Data[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged C++ I'd suggest you use C++ features...

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
struct Data
{
  unsigned int year;
  std::string schoolWin;
  unsigned int scoreWin;
  std::string schoolRunnerUp;
  unsigned int scoreRunnerUp;

  Data() 
      : year(0)
      , schoolWin("winning school")
      , scoreWin(0)
      , schoolRunnerUp("loosing school")
      , scoreRunnerUp(0){}
}

// In main
std::vector<Data> my_data(100); // Create and initialize 100 instances of "Data".
```

Answer (score 1):

Note this error:

```
project5.cpp(191) : error C2664: 'initializeStructure' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Data [100]' to 'Data &'
```

The argument NCAAStats you defined for initializeStructure() is a *reference* to one struct of type NCAAStats, which you can't use like an array (I assume that's what you were going for). You'll have to change it to a *pointer* (`Data *` or `Data[]`) to match the type you're actually passing as an argument.